# How do I embed my GUI in Windows explorer?

Tags: c++, windows, explorer

I want to add an option to explorer (in windows) like the 'preview pane' but only an 'edit pane'. The idea is that I have text files that I want to edit, but I dont want to open an application to edit the file. I want to just click over in the edit pane and make the edits. Any suggestions what API's I can use to extend explorer in this way? (More than just 'look at the shell api: I have and I dont know which will allow me to accomplish this).

Comment: http://drdobbs.com/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=184402922

Comment: @MitchWheat it seems that article is meant for windows 95. while i will look into the article in more depth a bit later, do you know if there is a more up to date version?

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement PropertyHandler. 
See Windows SDK \Samples\winui\Shell\AppShellIntegration\PropertyHandlers.

Each property is described by property schema XML file. This property schema must be registered with PSRegisterPropertySchema(). Property handler implements IInitializeWithXXX, IPropertyStore and optionally IPropertyStoreCapabilities. You have to register CLSID of your implementation for each file extension you want to handle (.txt in your case).

Comment: I dont understand what file properties has to do with embedding my gui into explorer.

Comment: It is not about file properties -the Windows Property System is an extensible read/write system of data definitions that provides a uniform way of expressing metadata about Shell items. In Windows Vista and later it enables you to store and retrieve metadata for Shell items (files, folders, emails, or contacts). A property is an individual piece of metadata associated with a Shell item. So you can use this metadata in order to allow the user to edit your file.

Comment: I see what you are saying, i think. The thing is that I want my own GUI present. A simple example of where this is useful is in previewing code. I would like the code that appears in the preview to be syntax highlighted. This isnt possible with a simple PropertyHandeler

Comment: your own GUI is also possible, see this [article](http://www.rttsoftware.com/Manuals/STIndex.htm?pageURL=ST/French/ColumnPropertyHandlers.htm)